# Create an alias for razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm playing with asp.net razor pages.

I've created default asp.net core 2.1 application then added 3 pages:

[image]

By [default convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio) pages will available in path:

```
Page1 -> http://localhost/Page1
Page2 -> http://localhost/Folder/Page2
Page3 -> http://localhost/Page3
```

And now I want to add an alias for page2, e.g. something like this:

```
Page1 -> http://localhost/Page1
Page2 -> http://localhost/Page2
Page2 -> http://localhost/Folder/Page2
Page3 -> http://localhost/Page3
```

Is it possible to create additional route/alias for this page without [adding-file-as-link](https://grantwinney.com/visual-studio-add-file-as-link/)?

Specifying page route in @page

```
@page "/Page2"
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Page2";
}

<h2>Page2</h2>
```

makes page2 available as `http://localhost/Page2`, but not as `http://localhost/Folder/Page2` :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with [`AddPageRoute(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-a-page-route). Here's an example for your situation:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Folder/Page2", "/Page2");
    });
```

Comment: Nice approach. I guess I can add a custom attribute  (something like `[AdditionalRoute("/Page2")]`) to my razor pages (which inherit PageModel) and register them all via reflection in Startup.cs

Comment: You could consider using a custom convention to help with that, depending upon your specific requirements. For example, a [folder route model convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1#folder-route-model-convention) would allow you to write code to automate the solution above for multiple pages. It's a bit more advanced but might be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

This, may help.
https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC

> T4MVC is a T4 template for ASP.NET MVC apps that creates strongly typed helpers that eliminate the use of literal strings in many places.

It will generate literal paths for your views, then you could return different views from the same action.

```
if (someCondition){
    return View(this.ViewNames.Page2)
}
else {
    return View(this.ViewNames.Folder_Page2)
}
```